# After up dating my joomla to 3.4.3 font family change

Tags: joomla-3.x

Hi Seniors, 
            I updated my joomla to 3.4.3, after updating its font family accidentally change  . Now i want to restore my previous font family on my client site. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add some more information like what font you did use and how you included it? Which template are you using?

Comment: This is the site (http://www.kabarthit.com/) and i want to change the font to  Zawgyi-One . I want to make this font default font .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a custom.css in your template folder (/templates/jsn_mico_pro/css/styles/custom.css). It overrides your font with Verdana and Arial.

```
/* Set font style for body */
body {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
}
...
```

Just remove the content from this file and you should be fine. It's very unlikely that Joomla itself changed that font. Maybe you made a template update?

Comment: i do that but the problem still exists

Comment: Did you upload the file? It is still the same...

Comment: i remove the content of the file but i dont know that from where it's taking the same font family (font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;) and i need this font (body {
 font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-size: 100%;

Comment: sorry (body {
 font-family: Zawgyi-One, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-size: 100%;

Comment: Probably the file is cached? Try to clear the Joomla cache. Your Zawgyi-One font is still there (in template.css) but it gets overriden by the font in custom.css.

Comment: hi thanks Sir .. problem solved but from another file custom.css.php . Thank you so much

Comment: @Shehryar please mark the answer as Accepted if information provided is helpful ;)